# FileUpload Without Servlet

Tags: android, apache, http

I have a very small web server in an Android app which I want to POST a file to in a Multipart POST request. I believe that [FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/) makes this possibly however it requires a servlet which I do not have.

Is there a similar method that I can use with just an HttpRequest?

Comment: I have only done very few web application hence this question might sound stupid. How actually do you have a web server, but do not have a servlet? Why can't you just make one since the web application belongs to you?

Comment: I am trying to keep the server extremely simple (I literally need one url) so I am just modifying [This](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/org/apache/http/examples/ElementalHttpServer.java.html) since all of the dependencies are already in Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a library that provides an entirely Java implementation of WebSockets that ended up being both faster, and much easier to use than using HTTP Multi-part POST requests.

[Java-WebSockets](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) via Github.

If you would like an example of how it is being used for my question, here is the code I ended up writing and using. Please don't mind the mess, it was for a hackathon.

- [Server](https://github.com/anstosa/NFCFU/blob/master/android/src/com/nfcfu/android/websocketServer/AndroidWebsocketServer.java) (receiving files)
- [Client](https://github.com/anstosa/NFCFU/blob/master/uploader/src/main/java/com/nfcfu/desktop/SendFileWebSocket.java) (sending files)